# Find a trigonometric integral over $[0, 2\pi]$ by converting to complex form and using residues

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Evaluate the integral 
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{3-2\cos \theta +\sin\theta}\,\mathrm d\theta.
$$

---

This must be solved by using $d \theta =  dz/(iz)$ and transforming $\sin, \cos$ to complex form, but I am stuck after transforming it.
 It is now $$\frac{1}{(2i+1)z^2 - 6i z + (2i+1)}$$ I don't know how to complete it now to find the singularities and solve by the residue theorem.

Comment: @Epictetus: Why did the OP use the complex-analysis tag??!

Comment: this must be solve by using d theta = (dz/iz) and sin , cos will be in Z form , but i am stuck after transforming it to the complex !

Comment: it is now 
1/([2i+1]z^2 - 6i z + [2i+1] )
i dont know how to complete it now to find the singularities and solve by resduie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With complex methods we have that
$$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{dt}{3-2\cos t+\sin t}=\oint_{C}\frac{1}{3-z-z^{-1}+\frac{z-z^{-1}}{2i}}\frac{dz}{iz}=\oint_{C}\frac{1}{3zi-z^2i-i+\frac{z^2-1}2}dz$$
where $C$ is the unit circle.

Consider
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{3zi-z^2i-i+\frac{z^2-1}2}=\frac{2}{z^2(1-2i)+6zi-2i-1}$$
A trivial factorisation gives
$$f(z)=\frac{2}{(1-2i)(z+\frac{i}{1-2i})(z+\frac{5i}{1-2i})}$$
You can then compute the residues and use the residue theorem

Comment: thanks , but how you factorize this one ?

Comment: With the discriminant that is negative...

Comment: the sin t has a coefficient of 1/2i right  ?

Comment: $\sin t=\frac{z-z^{-1}}{2i}$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: try using the substitution $u=\tan \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$.

Comment: this must be solve by using d theta = (dz/iz) and sin , cos will  be in Z form  , but i am stuck after transforming it to the complex !